# How can I use a parameter as a filter criteria with 'dplyr' in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the package *dplyr* in R. With the filter function, I would like to use a parameter as filter criteria. How can I proceed?

Instead of writing this

```
b = dplyr::filter(a, Note == "N.6.2", Liability == R.val.1)
```

(where Note and Liability are column names in the table "a").

I would like to have that

```
R.cat.1 = "Liability"
b = dplyr::filter(a, Note == "N.6.2", R.cat.1 == R.val.1)
```

The second method does not produce an error, but it produces an empty table, "b".

Comment: You assign the string "Liability" to the variable `R.cat.1` but use this variable as column name in the `filter()` expression. You should put it on the other side, i.e. `dplyr::filter(a, Note == "N.6.2", R.val.1 == R.cat.1)` assuming that `R.val.1` is the column in the data.frame `a`.

Comment: See here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html `filter(iris, .data[["Sepal.Length"]] < 5)`

Comment: Also - make sure that you have spelled it correctly. This is usually why `filter` returns empty data frames.

Comment: Thanks @Phil and the others, it works very well !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you what you want:

```
R.cat.1 = "Liability"
b = dplyr::filter(a, Note == "N.6.2", !!rlang::sym(R.cat.1) == R.val.1)
```

You can learn more about how this works by reading [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) and [programming in the tidyverse](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: Hey @seagullnutkin, what does operator `!!` represents in R?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. The solution I use is based on the bang-bang operator (`!!`). I don't know if this is the most elegant/concise/efficient method, and I would suggest reading the documentation on the tidy evaluation (https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html).

```
x <- 'Sepal.Length'
iris %>%
dplyr::filter( !!rlang::sym(x) > 7.5)

1          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
2          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
4          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
5          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
6          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
```

Otherwise, as suggested by @Phil you can use.

```
dplyr::filter(iris, .data[[x]] > 7.5)
```

Comment: Oh! I guess I misunderstood the question. This is obviously what you are looking for if it is the variable itself you want to change by assignment.